# program giving different output than what i expected

Tags: operator-keyword, xor

```
nt main()
{
    cout << ('a'^'b');
}
```

when  i wrote this simple code(in C++) program giving the "3" output. but it must be "1".
do you know why? is there problem with the xor operator??

Comment: im sorry i made typo. it must be 3 and 1!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with XOR and the result of 3 is correct.

```
   'a' XOR 'b'
-> 0x61 XOR 0x62          (hex, per ASCII)
-> 01100001 XOR 01100010  (binary)
-> 00000011               (only these bits differ)
-> 3                      (decimal)
```

Consider the following, which is 1 - why?

```
'`' ^ 'a'
```

Comment: i have been working for 5 hours. i think i get messed up :). you are right. output is "3". Thanks a lot..